# Hivexmlserde, not able to create table

Tags: xml, hive

I'm trying to use Apache hive xml serde so that I can create table with serde properties and load xml data to it. I downloaded Apache hivexml serde and added it. But while creating table, I'm getting error return code 1, class not found error.

Comment: The error is not informative. Try to find full Exception. Also please include steps you did. Like ADD jar blabla, create table sentence, etc

Comment: Share your `create table syntax` and whole `stacktrace` so that people can help you answer the question. with the given information, it's impossible.